# How to set environment variables in heroku-django project?

Tags: django, heroku, django-settings

I have this code in my settings.py..

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

I tried setting environment variable using this in heroku bash

```
export EMAIL_HOST_USER=xxx
```

and also

```
heroku config:set EMAIL_HOST_USER=xxx
```

None of the both method worked for me.
How can i set environment variable in heroku?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

okk.. found the answer!!

instead of

```
heroku config:set EMAIL_HOST_USER=xxx
```

writing

```
heroku config:add EMAIL_HOST_USER=xxx
```

solves problem..